# I used objectbox in my android project, I deleted the "build" folder, it can't "run" success

Tags: objectbox

[Delete directory "build"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OscqR.png)

[Run "app" failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7vJL.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As the bot says, you should include more details like text instead of links to images. Or at least add the images to Stack Overflow directly.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the build folder code generated by ObjectBox is deleted as well. To re-generate it, re-build your project. For example in Android Studio using Build > Make Project.

Source: https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started#generate-objectbox-code